# Why my equation is giving wrong results?

Tags: c++

**Why I am still getting values above 1.0 ?**

When trying to implement this graph:

[image]

Using [**this**](http://www.webmath.com/equline1.html) site to provide me the simple math equations of both lines `/` `\` which is `y = (1/3)x + 1` or `y = (-1/3)x + 1` respectively when I put it in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    input = GenerateRandom(-3.0, 3.0); // this function works fine
    output = FuzzyFunction(input); // get crisp outputs
    std::cout << "input: " << input << " - output: " << output << " \n";
}

// stuff    

double FuzzyFunction(double inputVal)
{
    outputVal = (1.0 / 3) * inputVal + 1;
    return outputVal;
}
```

Then the outputs are something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you include some expected output examples?

Comment: Why would you expect a positive number PLUS ONE to be anything less than one?

Comment: The function is doing exactly what you told it. Looking at the first line, `input = 2.74548`. Multiply this by `1.0 / 3` and then do `+ 1` and you get `1.91516`.  If you don't want to get `1.91516` then you either have to use a different input or a different equation in the function...

Comment: @Andrew I made a terrible logical mistake

Comment: @M.M thanks. I posted the answer

Comment: The graph in the function image is actually  y = 1 - |x|/3 , (in mathematical notation)

Comment: Highest x case : (1/3)*3+1 => 2. So will get answers up to 2.

Comment: I thought by giving negative inputs, the function as whole will flip and work fine. I guess I was mistaken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a terrible logical mistake. I needed this in my `FuzzyFunction()`:

```
if(inputVal<0)
    outputVal = (1.0/5) * inputVal + 1;
else if (inputVal > 0)
    outputVal = (-1.0 / 5) * inputVal + 1;
else
    outputVal = 0;
```

Correct Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The slope for positive inputs should be negative:

```
double FuzzyFunction(double inputVal)
{
    if (inputVal < 0)
        outputVal = (1.0 / 3) * inputVal + 1;
    else
        outputVal = (-1.0 / 3) * inputVal + 1;
    return outputVal;
}
```